# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Future' and 'int'

Tags: python

I use Future Functions of Python to download data. However, I cannot download because of an error:

> '<' not supported between instances of 'Future' and 'int'

Could you please suggest to me a solution?

```
progress = tqdm.tqdm(total=len(jobs))
futures = []
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
    for job in jobs:
        id, _, type, date, url = job
        filename = f'./data/{id}/{type}/{date}.txt.gz'
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            progress.update()
        else:
            f = exe.submit(download, job)
            f.add_done_callback(progress.update)
            futures.append(f)
for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in `f.add_done_callback(progress.update)`. When the job is done, `progress.update` is called with the future as argument. But it should be called with a number. Try to change to

```py
f.add_done_callback( lambda _: progress.update() )
```